# Finding all .ODTs, zipping them and bringing them to the desktop

Tags: find, zip

I want to find all the .ODTs in my $HOME directory, zip them and bring the zip file to the desktop. By doing `find -type f -iname "*.odt"`, I get:

```
./Programmierung/Hash bang.odt
./Schreibtisch/Alles/Tuberkulose/ Plan_tuberculose.odt
./Schreibtisch/Alles/Mirzanejad_Recueillement.odt
./Schreibtisch/Alles/Der Artikel/Ander/Déictiques de l'article.odt
./Schreibtisch/Alles/Der Artikel/Ander/Le plan.odt
./Schreibtisch/Alles/Der Artikel/Ander/Bibliographie.odt
./Schreibtisch/Alles/Geschrieben/corpus_historicité.odt
./Eifersucht/Ander/Le_plan_de_l'exposé_de_la_jalousie.odt
./Dokumente/Chant de guerre/Lieder/Bibliographie_Chants de guerre.odt
./Dokumente/Komparastik/Le_plan_de_Harriet.odt
./Dokumente/Komparastik/Harriet_Abji.odt
```

I have 11 files and I expect to have a zip file that contains this 11 files and then move it to the desktop. I do:

```
zip My_odts $(find -type f -iname "*.odt") && mv ~/My_odts.zip ~/Schreibtisch
```

[Schreibtisch=desktop]

But the content of **MY_odts.zip** is three directories: *desktop, documents and a directory that I've created*(instead of all my ODTs), and in this three directories I see some of my ODTs and not all of them. What am I doing wrong? I want to have all my ODTs and I don't know why those directories are in my zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you intend to do is to not preserve the directory structure of the files in the .zip (which is not the default behavior)

But looking at the manpage for `zip`, the `-p` switch does exactly what you want:

```
-j
--junk-paths
          Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do  not
          store  directory names. By default, zip will store the full path
          (relative to the current directory).
```

So your original command has to be modified as follows:

```
zip -j My_odts $(find -type f -iname "*.odt") && mv ~/My_odts.zip ~/Schreibtisch
```

Additionally it's not necessary that you have to move the file after creation, instead you can directly specify the path as part of the zip command

```
zip -j ~/Schreibtisch/My_odts.zip $(find ~ -type f -iname "*.odt")
```

Comment: Thanx, it solved the problem of  **directories**  and I see my ODTs in my zip, but some of my ODTs are not there. I see  **zip warning: name not matched: Plan_tuberculose.odt** in front of them.

Comment: @Coditoergosum Those files are either symlinks of files that are already in the zip (duplicate name) or symlinks `zip` could not resolve due to it being a broken link or due to it not having permissions to. Can you provide an `ls -ltr` for "Plan_tuberculose.odt"?

Comment: `ls -ltr` = `drwxrwxr-x 2 m m     4096 Jul 10 22:48 Tuberkulose`

Answer (score 2):

> *I'd like to know if it's possible to put all files in a directory (instead of zipping them) and then bring the directory to the desktop.*

You sure can. Use any method you wish to copy them to a destination directory, then move the directory to ~/Desktop , either with a GUI File Manager, or with the shell command

```
mv  -v ~/DIRECTORYWHEREVERTHEFILESARE/* ~/Desktop/
```

Since ODT files are already zip-compressed, this might save some processing time, and the size difference between a folder containing ODT files and a zip file of ODT files is small.

Now, to create a folder under ~Desktop named destination, then search for each file under /home and move each, a possible solution would be

```
cd ~/Desktop && mkdir destination && find ~/ -type f -iname  "*.odt" -exec mv {} ~/Desktop/destination \;
```

Comment: but how can I do that by a script? I can create a directory, move all files in it and then copy it to desktop, but I want to do it directly with something like that  I used for zipping them.

Comment: Here. we ask one question at a time, so there's a database created by each question and answer for others to help. I answered the last question you posed.